# Why does my drop down menu move all the main links below with the siblings?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a pretty simple CSS/JS drop down menu.  The problem is, when I click on select1, select 2 and 3 also drop down with the rest of the children links. http://codepen.io/donnaloia/pen/GqiKl
This shows exactly what I'm talking about.  How do I fix this?

## HTML

```
<div class='dropdown'>
  <h1 class='title'>Select1</h1>
  <ol class='drop'>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Pineapple</li>
    <li>Mango</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class='dropdown'>
  <h1 class='title'>Select2</h1>
  <ol class='drop'>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Pineapple</li>
    <li>Mango</li>
  </ol>
</div>


<div class='dropdown'>
  <h1 class='title'>Select3</h1>
  <ol class='drop'>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Pineapple</li>
    <li>Mango</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: table;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 11pt;
  color: #FC3;
  line-height: normal;
  text-align: left;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.dropdown .title {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 45px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #FC3;
  line-height: 45px;
}
.dropdown .title:after {
  content: '';
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  border-width: 5px 4px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #FC3 transparent transparent transparent;
}
.dropdown .drop {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: 1px;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #FC3;
}
.dropdown .drop li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
}
.dropdown .drop li:hover {
  background: #FC3;
  color: #FFF;
}

.select .title {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.select .title:after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

## JS

```
$('.dropdown .title').on('click',function(){
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('select').find('.drop').toggle();
});
$('.dropdown .drop li').on('click',function(){
  var $this = $(this), input = $this.text();
  $('.dropdown .title').text(input);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be so hard to instead `float: left` each of these divs? That way you don't need to worry about inline-block's behavior.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mKyfD